# Pass multiple specific files as one string arg from another java program

Tags: java, hadoop

I am trying to pass few specific paths as a string arg in one program to call another java program. I get an `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` error but when I pass the exact same arg in the command line it works perfectly

What is doable in command line:

```
program1  /filepath/{A,B,C}/*.zip
```

What I want to do that is giving me an error:

```
program2 [call program 1]:

status = ToolRunner.run(conf, program1, new String[]{"/filepath/{A,B,C}/*.zip"});
```

I am not sure how I can pass it that way, even if I want to pass all the paths and change the second program I am not sure how can I aggregate all the paths and assign it as input stream.

I appreciate your help, 
Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

`ToolRunner.run()` method receives as arguments:

- A `Configuration` object
- A `Tool` object
- A `String` array of arguments to be passed to the `Tool` object

Is your "program1" an object extending the `Tool` interface? Attending to the name you used, it seems it is more a refence to some "binary" or executable thing...

Please, have a look to the [documentation](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/api/org/apache/hadoop/util/ToolRunner.html).

`ToolRunner` is typically used in Hadoop applications as:

```
public final class MyMRClass extends Configured implements Tool {

    ...

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        int res = ToolRunner.run(new Configuration(), new MyMRClass(), args);
        System.exit(res);
    } // main

    @Override
    public int run(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Configuration conf = this.getConf();
        Job job = Job.getInstance(conf, "some job name");
        ...
    }

}
```

Comment: Yes I am using hadoop and I am passing more than one arg to it, but one of the args is /filepath/{A,B,C}/*.zip that when I pass it as the command argument it works fine and program understand the whole passes as one arg but when I pass it in string from another program, it gives me an error and doesnt accept it

Comment: and I am passing that arg as an input: MultipleInputs.addInputPath(job, new Path(args[1]), TextInputFormat.class, MapperClass.class);

Comment: Perhaps you should edit your original question since you are talking now about more than one argumnet passed, and in the original question only one was shown.